# How can I compute the SHAP values in a high dimensional dataset?

Tags: python, high-dimensional, shapley-value

I have a classiification problem with a dataset where the number of variables is very large, and the number of observations is small. Approximately 200 observations and 10000 variables. I am using a SVC model to make the predictions and I want to use SHAP to meassure the importance of each variable, to try and see of there is a subset of the 10000 variables that are more important for the predictions.

However, when I try to use shap with the `algorithm='auto'` parameter, it says that "it cannot allocate a vector of size 149GB. And when I try and use other algorithms like `algorith='partition'`, the code simply crashes.

So my question is: ¿Is there a way to compute shap values for this kind of high dimensional datasets?

I leave here a minimal code example to show my issue with some fake data:

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn.svm import SVC
    import shap

    X, y = make_classification(n_samples=200, n_features=10000, n_informative=100, scale=1, random_state=999)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25)

    # Build Support Vector Classifier on the train set
    model = SVC(C=0.5, kernel='sigmoid', gamma=0.01, probability=True)
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)

    # Compute SHAP values for the test data
    explainer = shap.Explainer(model.predict_proba, X_train)
    shap_values = explainer(X_test, max_evals=20001) # max_evals must be at least 2 * num_features + 1 

   # MemoryError: Unable to allocate 149. GiB for an array with shape (2000100, 10000) and data type float64


    explainer = shap.Explainer(model.predict_proba, X_train, algorithm='partition')
    # This simply kicks me out of the python terminal.
```

Comment: one approach would be to randomly subsample dimensions, compute SHAP vals on the subsampled dataset, and then aggregate.

Comment: hi have you ever found an answer? I found a package called fastshap. But I am not sure if it can work really?